# Java Sockets: Send multiple lines and receive multiple lines

Tags: java, sockets

I am sending multiple lines to a `ServerSocket` using a `PrintWriter`.

```
PrintWriter printWriter = ...
printWriter.write("1");
printWriter.write("2");
printWriter.write("3");
```

Then I am trying to receive it with a `BufferedReader`

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = ...
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
```

I am of course closing all the resources, I wrote this code only to visualize the problem.
That prints `123` but it is supposed to print `1`. How can I fix that?

Comment: `I do not like the solution` What is it that you do not like?

Comment: I messed up the link. I meant a workaround where you add a custom character at the end of every line and split the string afterwards.

Comment: You aren't sending any lines at all. Use `println()`, or add a line terminator yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--):

> readLine
>
> public String readLine()
>                   throws IOException
>
> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a **line feed ('\n')**, a **carriage return ('\r')**, or a **carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.**
>
> Returns:
>       **A String containing the contents of the line**, not including any line-termination characters, or null **if the end of the stream has been**
>   reached

The problem is that you are writing string without a line break. But `BufferedReader` expects one of the line characters mentioned above which you are not providing. It does output the whole buffer once the end of the stream is reached though.

so, use one of

```
printWriter.write("1\n");
```

```
printWriter.write("1\r\n");
```

```
printWriter.write("1\r");
```